# how to make reverse dns lookup in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a list of IPs. I need to make reveres DNS, i.e, I want the website name.

I tried the following:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("98.138.253.109");
String host = addr.getCanonicalHostName();
System.out.println(host);
```

But, the IP in my example is for yahoo.com, when I run the code, I get: ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com

I need a way so I can get the domain name by entering the IP.

Comment: The Ip address you are using is designated for only one host. As you can imagine yahoo probably has thousands of servers. They get assigned an allocation of ipaddresses which they then reuse as they see fit for internal allocation. The different servers under yahoo domain have different names and hence when you reference an ip address from a specific server you get the name for that specific server. For the general ipaddress for yahoo.com that might be hidden unless you want to to a nslookup and query a whole range of ipaddress to find yahoo.com allocations and generalize.yahoo.com is an alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IP Address in the code your provided resolves to yahoo because it is held by yahoo.

The Ip address you are using is designated for only one host. As you can imagine yahoo probably has thousands of servers. They get assigned an allocation of ipaddresses which they then reuse as they see fit for internal allocation. The different servers under yahoo domain have different names and hence when you reference an ip address from a specific server you get the name for that specific server. For the general ipaddress for yahoo.com that might be hidden unless you want to to a nslookup and query a whole range of ipaddress to find yahoo.com allocations and generalize from there.

Comment: -1 The OP wants to know why he gets `ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com` instead of just `yahoo.com`.

Comment: Correct, so edit your answer to say that and it will be an answer to the actual question. Your answer as it stands does not answer the question. Edit and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Using IP address to get the domain name (in the way you are expecting) might not be possible. There will be several servers for Yahoo and they all will map to the domain name yahoo.com. But they will have individual ip address and host name. The addr.getCanonicalHostName() returns the host name and not the domain name!

Comment: Exactly. When you have yahoo.com in your address bar, it's aliasing to a Yahoo! server whose host name may be different than the alias you're using to access it. `getCanonicalHostName` returns the former, but you want the latter. @WiliamA Try your code with a website that runs off only one server and you might find one that works the way you expect.