# Is there a way to get operating systems of remote host in java

Tags: java, networking, operating-system

I want to learn how I can get the type of operating system of remote host. When I use System.properties, I can learn my machine's properties but is there any way to learn for remote host?

Answer (score 3):

No. There are utilities such as nmap that can make an educated guess on an operating system based on open ports and other such things of a remote computer, but that's not Java related and it's not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask a remote method and get the result in its return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nmap4j](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nmap4j/index.php?title=Main_Page) for this operation. It is uses [nmap](http://nmap.org/) on background. And note that, it is bounded with nmap capabilities. This lib only provides you using nmap and parse nmap response. Nmap does not always return you exact information such as operating system

Answer (score 0):

If your machine talks **SNMP** you could query it for this information. There are Java implementations for SNMP. I would NOT hope that it would usually be the case though.

You could also **remotely execute** any command to get this info like via `ssh` or similar.

Some hope in using reverse DNS lookup: [how to make reverse dns lookup in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632352/how-to-make-reverse-dns-lookup-in-java).

Otherwise you have to use forensics like `nmap` and such.