# InetAddress to return the actual Public address of a website from IP

Tags: java, inetaddress

I have been trying several methods in some of the posts to get the actual Public Address from an IP(like facebook.com), but I have not been successful so far.  I have been trying the below code to get the web address of facebook :

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("31.13.76.68");
        String host = addr.getHostName();
        System.out.println(host);
    }
}
```

But what it returns me is this: `edge-star-mini-shv-01-sea1.facebook.com`. Is this the CNAME that is getting returned? I get the same results with `getCanonicalHostName`. Some websites even return corp address with gives me no information of the actual public address that IP is associated with. Is there a way to get the actual public address for a given IP? say 31.13.76.68 returns facebook.com, and `74.125.196.100` should return `google.com` and not `yk-in-f100.1e100.net` as I am getting in my case.

Comment: You are not able do so. All these monstrous names are result of "reverse DNS lookup".

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632352/how-to-make-reverse-dns-lookup-in-java

Comment: Right, seems like a duplicate and think there is no deterministic way it can be figured out?